# how to cycle through array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays

I know this question is simple, but I have little experience with arrays and am having difficulty. Anyway I have this array:

```
$variables=array("$value1" => "int",$value2 => "var",$value3 => "int");
```

I want to cycle through it and for each $value I would like to add

`$stmt->bindValue(1,$value, PDO::PARAM_INT);` if $value is 'int' or

`$stmt->bindValue(1,$value);` if $value is 'var'

and have the '1' increase as it cycles through the variables. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: post the code you have tried. This is a simple foreach with an if

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. if $value is 'var'? you mean string? Add? you mean numerically add? or concatenate? Please improve your question.

Comment: Everyone else seemed to understand just fine. Is English not your native tongue or are you just hating for no reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `foreach` loop lets you loop through your array. The `foreach ($array as $k=>$v)` syntax lets you define a variable to hold the current key (`$k`) and one for the current value (`$v`). I also used a simple variable that is incremented in every cycle (`$i`).

Then a simple `if`-`elseif` combo is used to do something different.

```
$i=1;
foreach ($variables as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v=='int') {
        $stmt->bindValue($i, $k, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    elseif ($v=='var') {
        $stmt->bindValue($i, $k);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This can be optimized further, I wanted to show the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($variables as $key => $value){

  switch ($value) {
        case "int":
            $stmt->bindValue($count, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
          break; 

        case "var":            
            $stmt->bindValue($count, $value);      
         break;

        default:
           exit("Invalid value");            

    }                
          $count++; 

}
```

Comment: +1 `switch` can also be a good way if there can be further cases. An `exit` seems a bit strict though ;).

Comment: The exit is indeed a showstopper, it was put there just to show op he can easily have a block to handle unexpected conditions! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution stef +1.

Answer (score 1):

Simple loop should do it

```
$x=0;
foreach($variables as $key=>$value)
{
  if($value=="var")
   {
     $stmt->bindValue($x,$key);
   }
   else
   { 
      $stmt->bindValue($x,$value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   }
  $x++;
}
```

Comment: You need the key in `bindValue`, not the value.